# Split Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

So I have a pandas column that looks like this:

```
full_name = pd.Series([
    'Reservoir 1 Compartment 1', 
    'Reservoir 1 Common Inlet', 
    'Reservoir 2 Compartment 1',
    'Vyrnwy Line 2 Balancing Tank 1', 
    'Reservoir 1'
])
```

I am trying to split it into two columns. The expected output should look like this:

```
[['Reservoir 1', 'Compartment 1'],
 ['Reservoir 1', 'Common Inlet'],
 ['Reservoir 2', 'Compartment 1'],
 ['Vyrnwy Line 2', 'Balancing Tank 1'],
 ['Reservoir 1', None]]
```

I have tried this:

```
res_compartment_split = pd.concat([full_name.str.split(r'\s\s*?(?=[A-Z])', expand=True)])
```

but I get this output

```
[['Reservoir 1', 'Compartment 1', None, None],
 ['Reservoir 1', 'Common', 'Inlet', None],
 ['Reservoir 2', 'Compartment 1', None, None],
 ['Vyrnwy', 'Line 2', 'Balancing', 'Tank 1'],
 ['Reservoir 1', None, None, None]]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `full_name.str.findall(r"(\D+(?:\d+|$))")`

Comment: Is it right to divide the size of each string in half?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! This works! Could you please post an answer explaining the regex?

Comment: @Lazyer it is not right to divide it in half. A probable pattern split would be at the end of the first digit (1, 2, etc.)

Comment: So, the space is always there? Only one?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

full_name = pd.Series([
    'Reservoir 1 Compartment 1', 
    'Reservoir 1 Common Inlet', 
    'Reservoir 2 Compartment 1',
    'Vyrnwy Line 2 Balancing Tank 1', 
    'Reservoir 1'
])

res = full_name.str.split('(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Z])', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> res
               0                 1
0    Reservoir 1     Compartment 1
1    Reservoir 1      Common Inlet
2    Reservoir 2     Compartment 1
3  Vyrnwy Line 2  Balancing Tank 1
4    Reservoir 1              None
```

Explanation of the regex pattern:

- `(?<=\d)` - positive lookbehind: ensures that there is a digit right before the separator, without consuming it
- `\s+` - separator: matches one or more whitespace
- `(?=[A-Z])` - positive lookahead: ensures that there is a letter (A to Z) right after, without consuming it

See it in action using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wmCFyH/1).

Also, you can see here why your pattern doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/nSmEEs/1 .

Answer (score 2):

You can extract strings that consist of any non-digits ending with one or more digits or end of string:

```py
full_name.str.findall(r"\s*(\D+(?:\d+|$))")
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `\D+` - one or more non-digits
  - `(?:\d+|$)` - one or more digits or end of string.
- `)` - end of the group.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aIgYFt/1).

Answer (score 1):

In your case the split point can be a **space**, **preceded with a digit**.

To match the preceding digit use *positive lookbehind*:

```
result = full_name.str.split(r'(?<=\d) ', expand=True)
```

Then you can set names to columns, e.g.:

```
result.columns = ['Res', 'Comp']
```

The result is:

```
             Res              Comp
0    Reservoir 1     Compartment 1
1    Reservoir 1      Common Inlet
2    Reservoir 2     Compartment 1
3  Vyrnwy Line 2  Balancing Tank 1
4    Reservoir 1              None
```